# Question about solving an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning ODE, and I found that people seldom check the domains of variables $x$ and $y$, which makes me confused. For example, suppose we have

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-4y}}{2}$

I know how to solve this equation. But I am confused about the scenario when $x^2-4y \leq 0$, can we then use $\sqrt{x^2-4y}=i\sqrt{4y-x^2}$?

Does this make sense? Do we need to consider complex solutions when solving ODE?

I share my way of solving the original equation and hope to know where I should modify it when solving the complex one.

let $t=x^2-4y$,then we have $\frac{dt}{dx}=2x-4\frac{dy}{dx}=-2\sqrt{t}$, then we can easily have $\sqrt{t}= -x+C$, i.e. $\sqrt{x^2-4y}=-x+C$

Comment: That's one of the problems when you just solve differential equations mechanically without paying attention to the constraint. To answer your question, you must consider that its ODE has a domain of validity and on it the solution it finds will make sense.

Comment: When $x^2-4y<0$, $i$ shows up.

Comment: Can you please show me how to find the constraint? When I learn PDE, it always has some domain on which the equation satisfies. But in ODE, these constraints become vague and ambiguous.

Comment: Your solution is correct and the doubt is unneccesssary.

Comment: Can you explain why it is unnecessary?